How would you make a ‘histomap’ of a fictional world?
Currently I’m working on a fictional world for my language and to build some history for my world I decided to map out some wars in it. I’ve been using MS Paint to do so but I’d really like some specialized software for this. To get an example for somewhat I’m looking for, search something like ‘History of the World’ or ‘History of Europe’ on Youtube. Sorry for not providing specific examples but if you could help me I would appreciate it! Thanks.

I don't know of a single tool that does what you're asking (animated map graphics with a narrative overlay or, at least, "frames" with instruction/notes). But there are a fair number of options in our list of worldbuilding resources. It's a good place to start.

World Anvil has a tool to allow you to upload a map and add layers and markers and stuff on top. I don't know of any more specialized software though.

As an alternative to the never ending search for a piece of software that never quite does what we want it to do...

There is a most excellent, incredibly inexpensive and very easy to use hardware suite called Pen-n-Paper! With a very little bit of practice you can easily churn out all the historical maps you'll ever need! You won't have to rely on someone else's symbol sets or arrow sweeps. This tool give you total control over the map making process!
